# Cloned windows ssd and now cant boot into it

Tags: dual-boot

i have two SSD. one runs Ubuntu and the other windows 10. I cloned my windows drive yesterday to a larger one and after i formated my old one now i can't boot into windows from the grub menu. In that grub menu I have now ubuntu, and two windows bootloaders sda2, sda3, tried to log in on both but windows system error pops up and restarts the pc. if i change boot priority i can boot just fine. i tried the grub repair but it still didnt do anything to fix that and i can now log in to just ubuntu from Grub. Thank you

Comment: To clarify... You have three drives... U, W1, W2. U has GRUB and boots Ubuntu. W1 is your original Windows drive, and it boots if you set the boot order correctly. W2 is the cloned Windows drive, and it also boots if you set the boot order correctly? Are you trying to boot with all three drives attached? What happens if you try to boot with only two attached (U and W1) or (U and W2)?

Comment: Is Windows fast startup on which sets hibernation flag. Grub only boots working Windows and that also means it cannot be hibernated. Can you directly boot the Windows drive from UEFI/BIOS. Are both systems in same boot mode, or both BIOS or both UEFI? Note that Windows updates turn fast start up back on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation